# Disable Tab Key For Input With Certain Div ID

Tags: javascript, html, key, input-field

I'd like to disable the tab key for a few input fields. But only for the ones with **div id="two"** and **div id="five"**. So when you hit the tab key, you go from field ***one*** to ***three***, to ***four***, and then to ***six***.

```
<form action="">
  <fieldset>
    <div id="one"><input type="text"/></div>
    <div id="two"><input type="text"/></div>
    <div id="three"><input type="text"/></div>
    <div id="four"><input type="text"/></div>
    <div id="five"><input type="text"/></div>
    <div id="six"><input type="text"/></div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Anyone know of a Javascript that can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/b9gsT/

You can use `tabindex` attribute:

```
<form action="">
  <fieldset>
    <div id="one"><input type="text"/></div>
    <div id="two"><input type="text" tabindex="-1"/></div>
    <div id="three"><input type="text"/></div>
    <div id="four"><input type="text"/></div>
    <div id="five"><input type="text" tabindex="-1"/></div>
    <div id="six"><input type="text"/></div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

If you want to do it with JavaScript, use `.tabIndex`:

```
function getEl(id){
  return document.getElementById(id);
}
getEl('two').childNodes[0].tabIndex=getEl('five').childNodes[0].tabIndex=-1;
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/b9gsT/1/

Note that the attribute is lowercase in XHTML (case-insensitive in HTML), but the property is case-sensitive: it's `.tabIndex` with the uppercase "I". On Firefox it works with a lowercase "i" too, but it doesn't on Chrome.